# How to pass data from onclick button to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing my first Jquery related website. I'm now stucked: how to pass data from button to variable ?

Script:

```
echo nl2br("<br><h1>".$row2['header']."</h1><br><h4 $style>".htmlentities($row2['text'])."</h4><hr><br>
<input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" data=".$row2['ID']." value="submit" onclick="return passID()">");
```

jQuery:

```
 function passid()
 {
     var ID=??????
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the row ID to the passID function in the inline onclick event.

```
<input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" data=".$row2['ID']." value="submit" onclick="return passID(".$row2['ID'].")">"
```

Then change your function to accept an ID variable

```
 function passid(rowId){
  var ID=rowId;    
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a alot, this worked! Is there possible pass multible variables with this btw?

Comment: Yes, as many as required. As long as you have a function with the correct definition available.

Comment: It seems to be able only pass numbers with that(?) Is there way to pass text with this?

Comment: Echo your HTML with single quotes around the variable

Answer (score 2):

```js
$("#identify_this_btn").click(function() {
  
  var data = $(this).attr("data"); // GET THE DATA IN ATTR
  event.preventDefault();
  alert(data);
  console.log(data);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="btn btn-default" id="identify_this_btn" type="submit" data="this_is_some_data" value="submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

On php:

```
echo '<input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return passId('.$row2['ID'].')">';
```

On javascript:

```
function passId(id){ console.log(id); }
```